# How to get lex conservation in lambda function

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-lex, amazon-connect

I am trying to integrate lambda with Amazon connect and Lex. I want to get all conversation happened with amazon lex and caller. How can I implement this?
Thanks,
Ganesh

Comment: That's an extremely broad question.  Do you have a specific task that you are trying to accomplish or can you describe what isn't working properly?

Answer (score 0):

In Lex console, you will an option to select Lambda under the Fulfillment section. Please select "AWS Lambda Function" there and select the Lambda you want to connect from the dropdown list.

[image: fulfillment screenshot]